# How to install PECL on a linux system

Tags: php, pecl

There are download sections for PECL extensions in http://pecl.php.net/ 
But I am not getting install steps for PECL *itself**. Following command does not work -

```
yum intall pecl
```

In my system, I have PECL installed, so I can install PECL extensions like this-

```
pecl install mailparse
```

But, in a system where running `pecl` command does not recognize the same, how to install PECL first on a Fedora 7  system (old  system).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Seems to me that you should do `yum install php-pear` to get pecl on your OS, not `yum install pecl`.

On Debian/Ubuntu with the [Ondrej PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php): `sudo apt-get install php-pear`

Comment: If anyobody have come here, wondering, like me, about how to install pecl on AWS linux and PHP 7, package is `php7-pear` and executable is `pecl7`

Comment: and if you are using the remi repo - all the binaries etc are in /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin.  I recommend symbolic linking these to their normal directories etc.

Comment: I am using php7.3.29 and I am not able to install pecl I tried ```sudo apt-get install php7.3-pear``` . E: Unable to locate package php7.3-pear. If i try it wothout version it installs for php 8. @baldrs